# Cannot get value of Attribute on a Ancestor node in XSLT

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

This is my first foray into XSLT, so I could have things totally wrong.  This is a minimum repro (that does fail), but in the final solution, I only know that the desired value is 2 levels up from the DETAIL node.

I have the following XSLT fragment (XSLT 1.0 and cannot upgrade to 2.0)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//DETAIL"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DETAIL">
    <br/>Current: <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    <br/>Ancestor: <xsl:value-of select="../../@Name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT Name="Desired">
    <CHILD>
        <DETAIL Name="NotTheDesired">
        </DETAIL>
    </CHILD>
</ROOT>
```

Which results in (notice no output for the ancestor attribute) when processed in IE 11 on Windows 10, but works (gives the proper value for the ancestor's attribute) when processed with .NET XslCompiledTransform.

```
Current: NotTheDesired
Ancestor:
```

I have tried numerous variations of this theme including using string() around the select expression etc.  Every permutation that I have tried as resulting in no output for the ancestor's attribute value.

I did not write the code to do the transform in IE, but below is what is being done.  xml is a serialized version of the xml.  xsltDoc is the xlst

```
var xmlDoc = new windows.ActivbeXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXml(xml);
xmlDoc.resolveExternals = true;
var htmlString = xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
```

Comment: Your XSLT fragment looks fine. Testing it at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mU shows all is happy! Have you go any other templates in your XSLT? Thanks!

Comment: So how do you run the XSLT with IE, using script, using an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction? If you want to post a minimal repro, then please show a minimal but complete stylesheet together with an explanation how you use that XSLT in IE. When I load http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016020901.xml which uses http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016020901.xsl then both Edge as well as IE show `Current: NotTheDesired
Ancestor: Desired` on Windows 10.

Comment: @martin Edited the question to include information on how the transform is performed.  Will attempt to cut down enough stuff to make a complete repro.

Comment: How about posting minimal but complete snippets that allow us to reproduce the problem? `ActivbeXObject` has a typo so it is certainly not any code running at all. Stackoverflow allows you to include HTML and Javascript snippets in an executable way, so use that feature so that we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Martin I started a simple repro, thing is that it worked.  I bounced this back to the person who wrote the script to see what my simple repro was doing differently from what he was doing.  He has not gotten back to me.  I will post more once I know what is going on.  I found many ways to do the transform while researching my repro, so could be he is not doing what I thought (from wading through the code) he was doing.  I did test with the template and xml provided, but not with the scripting code provided.  Hence the typo,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the code that was doing the transform loaded the XML into a jQuery XMLDocument, did some processing including striping off the DocumentElement and then serialized it and loaded it into a Microsoft XML via the loadXml.  (Even though all the nodes I wanted were still there, something in that process obviously does not produce desired results.)  It only took the original developer about 2 hours to figure this mess out.  Once I convinced him to just save the original string and load that before calling the transform, everything worked as it should.  No wonder I felt that some of the client processing was not working correctly.

Thanks to all for saying things that got me looking in the right direction to prod the script writer.